# free space inconsistency

Tags: disk-usage, disk, gparted

why does `df` command and `gparted` show different free space?

In my case, I have:

```
$ df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size    Used   Avail   Use%   Mounted on
[...]
/dev/sda4      ext4      184G    173G    1.6G   100%   /home
```

*and the same results from Nautilus*
while gparted shows:

```
Size         Used                Unused
186.47GiB    175.58 GiB (94%)    10.90 GiB (6%)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the output from `df` with no parameters?

Comment: yes, it have -hT; updated OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Previously answered here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=149980&sid=915c2ed000b07cb3363fdf0a40ecdac5#p149980)

> Gparted will be looking at actual inodes and disk-level info to determine how much is free, whereas df will be looking using the filesystem tools themselves[...]